# error " Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" on Mysql connection closing

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm calling to this class from other part of my appiclation and it's working fine. However I would like to close every single mysql connection which has been open.

This is my class to connect to my database:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;





public class BACENGQueryDatabases {
    public String Query;


    public BACENGQueryDatabases(String Query){
        this.Query = Query;
    }

    public ResultSet LoadQuery() throws Exception{  

    // Accessing Driver From Jar File
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//Get credentials from Property file
BACENGPropertiesFile user = new BACENGPropertiesFile("user.cred");
BACENGPropertiesFile passwd = new BACENGPropertiesFile("passwd.cred");
BACENGPropertiesFile database = new BACENGPropertiesFile("database.system");
BACENGPropertiesFile DBServer = new BACENGPropertiesFile("DBServer.system");
BACENGPropertiesFile DBPort = new BACENGPropertiesFile("DBPort.system");

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


//DB Connection

          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+DBServer.properties()+":"+DBPort.properties()+"/"+database.properties()+"",""+user.properties()+"",""+passwd.properties()+"");       
    //DB Connection
           String sql =Query; 
           pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    //System.out.println(sql); //Just to test

          rs=pst.executeQuery();

     con.close();
    return rs;


    }

}
```

The problem is happening when I try to close the connection trought:

```
con.close();
```

Then, the output is:

```
"Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"
```

Comment: I highly doubt that you get that error from closing the connection, you get it later on after the connection is closed (which closes the statement, which closes the resultset) and you try to use the resultset anyway.

Comment: Then, would be possible to close the connection keepig the resultset open?

Comment: @Sallyerik No that is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you close a `Connection` like you do in your code, then any dependent objects like the `ResultSet` created from that connection are closed as well. You either need to keep your connection open as long as you need your result set, use a `CachedRowSet` or transfer the contents of the result set to something else before returning it.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I've transfered it to String or ArryList depend on the case and then I close the connection. Also I realise that my problem was in other part of my code which is calling to other class to update the database. I've closed this others connection with con.close() and now my Max_used_connections in my database are 17 instead 500 or so. thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Well, the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) says “Calling the method close on a ResultSet object that is already closed is a no-op”, and [similarly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) “Calling the method close on a Connection object that is already closed is a no-op”, but I also discovered that the database driver vendors happily violate this contract.

Comment: @Holger I am not entirely sure what the point is of your comment; yes not all drivers adhere completely to the spec, but this is one of the basic requirements that has existed since JDBC 1. Re `close()` behavior: that was a clarification/improvement added in JDBC 4, so if you use a JDBC 3 driver, or a driver that wasn't carefully updated to the spec then you might get the behavior that was valid in older JDBC specs.